What is the natural module?
Lemma 2.9 of [1]:
Let $\operatorname{char}(K) \neq 2 $ and let $G$ be $\operatorname{Spin}(m,K)$, $n=\operatorname{rank} G$, and let $V$ be the natural $m$-dimensional module. Suppose $f\in G$ and $f^2$ is $-1$ on $V$. Then $m$ is even….
In the proof, it says on $V$, $f$ has eigenvalues $i$ and $-i$ only. Since an eigenspace is nonsingularly paired with its dual, $m$ must be even. Let $Z$ be the kernel of the action of $G$ on $V$; $|Z|=2$.
What is the natural $m$-dimensional module the author is referring to? And what is the action of $G$ on $V$? Is it the orthogonal space of $\operatorname{SO}$?
[1] Griess, Robert L. “Elementary Abelian $p$-Subgroups of Algebraic Groups.” Geometriae dedicata 39.3 (1991): 253–305.

As you suspected, $\operatorname{Spin}(m, K)$ acts on $V := K^m$ via $\operatorname{Spin}(m, K) \to \operatorname{SO}(m, K)$, and $Z$ is the kernel of the projection.  Did you really mean to have a simple $n$ that you do not otherwise use, or should it be $m$?

Thank you! So when it says $f^2$ acts as $-1$ on $V$, it means the image of $f^2$ in SO is $-I_{m}$?

Re, yes.
